# Are there "continuous" random variables without a density function?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, radon-nikodym

Assume you have a random varaible with a cumulation distribution function $F(x)=P(X\le x)$. This function will always be right-continuous, but assume that it also is left-continuous. Then there are no single values which have a positive probability.

Will this random variable always have a probability density function which can be integrated?

By the Radon-Nikodym theorem what we have to show is that the measure induced by $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue-measure. However, I do not know how to show this.

Comment: You cannot show absolute continuity. Cantor function is a well known example of  a continuous distribution function with no density.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, thank you very much!